# Excel VBA: Return first occurrence of a word in a column? The last?

Tags: excel, vba

Say I have, in an arbitrary column, these values from row 1 down:

```
1 A
2 A
3 A
4 A
5 B
6 B
7 B
8 A
9 A
10 A
```

I want to be able to say start=5 is the first B and last=7 is the last B. If there are no B's return 0 for both first and last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work for you or do you need two separate functions?

```
Function findValues(place As String, val As String, rng As Range) As Integer
    Dim r As Range
    findValues = 0
    For Each r In rng
        If InStr(r.Value2, val) > 0 Then
            findValues = r.Row
            If LCase(place) = "first" Then
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Use like this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B1:B10")
Dim i As Integer
i = findValues("first", "B", rng)
i = findValues("last", "B", rng)
```

Depending on how big of a Range you need to check, this could take a while.

Comment: I'm moreso trying to assign row numbers to variables and not making any assumptions about the size of the column

Comment: You could define rng as Range("B:B") in this case

Answer (score 17):

Don't forget that in VBA you still have access to a wealth of built-in Excel functions. Examples (assuming your data is in column 1):

Find the first B...
`Columns(1).Find(What:="B", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False).Row  'Returns 5`

Find the last B...
`Columns(1).Find(What:="B", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row  'Returns 7`

If B is not found, then an error is returned. We can take advantage of this by using error handling to return 0 if B is not found. Putting it all together...

```
Sub DoTest()
  Dim RowFirst As Integer, _
      RowLast As Integer
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  RowFirst = Columns(1).Find(What:="B", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
  RowLast = Columns(1).Find(What:="B", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  RowFirst = 0
  RowLast = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer because it uses build in functionality of VBA and doesn't require developers to write redundant code.

Comment: Is it better to use `range` with addressing the final row instead of `columns` for performance?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way.

```
Sub FindFirstLast()

    Dim vaValues As Variant
    Dim vaFilter As Variant
    Dim lFirst As Long
    Dim lLast As Long

    Const sFIND As String = "B"

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        'Get a 1-d array from a column
        vaValues = .Transpose(Sheet1.Range("A1:A10").Value)

        'Use match to get the first instance
        lFirst = .Match(sFIND, vaValues, False)

        'Filter on the values
        vaFilter = Filter(vaValues, sFIND)

        'Assumes they're all together
        lLast = lFirst + UBound(vaFilter)
    End With

    Debug.Print lFirst, lLast

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been using Kevin Pope's method in a few applications but found that it would sometimes include stuff I didn't want. Thought I'd share my experience and solution.

Recently I realized that if I had something like this:

```
Mouser  EPM1270GT144I5
Mouser  EPM1270GT144I5
Mouser  GRM32DR71E106K
Mouser  GRM32DR71E106K
TTI     GRM32DR71E106KA12L
Avnet   GS816273CC-250I
Avnet   GS816273CC-250I
```

and was looking for this: GRM32DR71E106K

It would return the two I was searching for and the third that starts with the same string.

I needed to adapt to search for EXACT matches. The fix was pretty easy:

```
 Public Function findValues(Val As String, Rng As Range, Optional place As Integer) As Integer
        Dim R As Range
        findValues = 0
        For Each R In Rng
            If StrComp(R.Value2, Val) = 0 Then
    '        If InStr(R.Value2, Val) > 0 Then
                findValues = R.Row
                If place = 1 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

I hope someone finds that useful.